# Can you make a mesh follow another mesh with Cloth Sim?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

Basically, I have a mesh that is being controlled by Rigid bodies and another one by a Cloth Sim that is pinned.

Is it possible to have the pinned part of the cloth mesh follow the other mesh that has rigid bodies?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is.  The simple solution to your problem as I understand it is to parent the cloth modified mesh to the rigid body mesh.  Then, the pinned vertices will follow the rigid body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to link the pinned of the vertices and the rigid body to a bone.

Create a bone and apply the metarig to the cloth with empty groups first.
[image: applying the metarig]

After this, delete the Bone vertice group and copy its name to the name of the pinned group.

[image: changing name]

Now parent the bone to the rigid body(select the bone first).

And there you go.
[image: result]